# Is this hash function unique?

Tags: hash, unique, hash-function

Will the following generated hash be always different for different keys,  assuming the hash integer is never overflown?
The key is supposed to contain ascii coded chars.

I think that is the case since I can not think of an exceptional case.

```
char[] arr = "abcd"
int hash = 0
for (int i=0; i<arr.size; i++) {
    hash += (i+1) * arr[i]
}
```

**EDIT1:** While the following are technically correct answers to my original question, I should have mentioned that the domain of the keys is that of valid email-ids. So, some ascii chars are not included. Nevertheless, I will run some tests and report. The only problem is enumerating all perms is possible only upto a small length.

Anyway, my requirement is to make unique ids based on email-ids and use them as primary keys in a db. Just don't want to use the mail-ids themselves.

**EDIT2:** Okay apparently, there are loads of collisions. for e.g., hash of 03N@gmail.com == hash of 00P@gmail.com

```
...
040 == 012
041 == 013
042 == 014
043 == 015
044 == 016
045 == 017
046 == 018
047 == 019
048 == 01:
...
```

I need a different hashing algorithm. Can you suggest any?

Comment: "Will the following generated hash be always different for different keys?" By definition of "hash function" the answer is "no". If the answer is "yes" -- don't call it a hash function.

Comment: you're taking a large value-space and "compressing" it to a smaller space. by definition there WILL be at least 2 input values that map to the same output.

Comment: There should be at least one collision

Answer (score 4):

No: 1*2 + 2*2 = 1*4 + 2*1 for example.

(`char[] arr = {'\u0002','\u0002'}` and `char[] arr = {'\u0004','\u0001'}`)

Answer (score 3):

These two strings would generate identical hashes:

```
"~ "
"@?"
```

The above consist entirely of printable ASCII characters.

A brute-force way of testing your algorithm would be simply to try all combinations of 2 characters, then perhaps all combinations of 3 or 4 characters, to get an idea of the uniqueness.

```
char key[5] = {0};
bool used[65536] = {0};
for (key[0] = " "; key[0] < 128; key[0]++)
    for (key[1] = " "; key[1] < 128; key[1]++) {
        if (used[hashcode(key)]) {
            printf("failed %s", key);
        else
            used[hashcode(key) = true;
        }
```

Comment: The two values you mentioned produce 190 and 253 respectively.

Comment: Oops, sorry @DebD.  I think it should be

Comment: Good catch,  @DebD.  My bad for not checking the ASCII table carefully before typing, must have read an octal value or something.  I'll try to correct the second one to "@?" instead of the erroneous "{A"

Answer (score 0):

Answering your additional question in your edit about seeking to improve your hash function, a small change you could make would be to multiply the each character by a prime number before adding to the total.  This will not guarantee no collisions, but should cut down on them, as each new term you add will will be spaced out more, and a multiple of a prime.  I'd skip the first few primes to get better spacing, so maybe multiply the first character by 11, the second by 13, the third by 17, the 4th by 19, and so forth.  If your strings are not too long, you will not need a very large table of primes.

If you really wanted to get fancy, you could look into generating a CRC, or using a linear feedback shift register technique to generate a signature.  In the latter, you would XOR the new character (or chosen bits of the new character) into the lowest 8 bits of the running total, then rotate the entire total by a number of bits.